# ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded question

Tags: sp.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js"); 
});
```

I have a question on this portion of the code. What is this `sp.js` means?

Answer (score 1):

**SP.js** is the default and mandatory reference file of SharePoint Client side object model. You can use this file to write JavaScript(ECMAScript) codes in web part pages or application pages by referencing the javascript file - ***"SP.JS"***.

In your code, you have already declared the file in your code in the document.ready event, and hence, you do not need to manually refer this again anywhere in your code. Also, *ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded* ensures that your code for **retrieveListItems** will load only after all the contents of **SP.js** has finished loading. This prevents any erroneous call in the page life cycle.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionToExecute, JavaScriptFileName)`

The above function accepts two parameters

1. A function name
2. Script file name

`functionToExecute` will be run only after the `JavaScriptFileName` is loaded. This way you can be sure the function that is internally used is available.

Example - Retrieve list items uses client object functions which are available in script file `sp.js`. So better to call the retrieve function only after loading `sp.js` file. If your JavaScript use SharePoint JavaScript Client Object Model, you need to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to delay your Client Object calls after SharePoint's core Javascript library is loaded. The function name is passed directly as parameter to the function.